# Postgresql - problem updating row with complex calculation

Tags: postgresql, javascript, area, mathematics

A calculation for the replacement value of a tree exists:

Variables:

```
index_price for species;
circumference of tree;
condition measures: vitality, root_injuries, stem_injuries,
  crown_injuries
(A condition measurement can be between 0 and 4, 0 worst, 4 best).
```

Calculated inputs:

```
price_per_cm2 for small tree: index_price/13.45
area_of_tree: (circumference*circumference)/(4 * pi)
condition_adjustment: (vitality + root_injuries + stem_injuries + 
  crown_injuries)/16
establishment cost: (area * 70 SEK) + 10000 SEK, or 75000 SEK, whichever 
  is smaller
```

The calculation is:

```
((Price per cm2 * area) * condition adjustments) + establishment cost.
```

So, with javascript, this works:

```
circumference = diamter * pi;
establishment_cost = (area * 70) + 10000 > 75000 ? 75000 : (area * 70) +
  10000;
replacement_price = 
    ((index_price/13.45)*((circumference*circumference)/(4*pi)) *
    ((vitality + root_injuries + stem_injuries + crown_injuries)/16)) +
    establishment_cost
```

With PostGreSQL psql I try:

```
update trees
set replacement_price = 
  ((index_price/13.45)*
  (((diameter*3.141592654)*(diameter*3.141592654))/(4*3.141592654)) *
  ((vitality + root_injuries + stem_injuries + crown_injuries)/16)) + 
  establishment_cost;
```

The query only works for one row, where the diameter is 4cm, in all other rows (diameters of 20cm and greater) replacement_price = establishment_cost, suggesting the start of the calculation is returning 0.

Can any talented mathematicians or SQLers help me find my error?

Eventually, I hope to place the code in a stored procedure, but thought I'd start with manual updates...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The part being equal to zero is likely `((vitality + root_injuries + stem_injuries + crown_injuries)/16))` should the sum be less than 16. Try dividing by `16.0` instead so you will have decimal results.

Comment: Yes, that was it! - the 4cm tree scored 4 in all the condition adjustments so that's why that one worked. Thanks @JGH